# How to index through <li of a <ul given by a class name

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html code similar to the following

```
<div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                <div>
                    <section >
                        <article>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                <ul    class='hover p-0  job-search-key-kgm6qi exy0tjh1'>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                    <li     <a....</a>    </li>
                                <ul/>
                                <div/>
                            <div/>
                        <article/>
                    <section/>
                <div/>
                <div/>
            <div/>
        <div/>
    <div/>
<div/>
```

Also, here's an image of the real code
[image]

I want to get all the links that are contained in the <li.... of the <ul where the class is named 'hover p-0  job-search-key-kgm6qi exy0tjh1'
I tried to use the following code, but it gives me an empty list

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/united-states-business-intelligence-analyst-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IN1_KO14,43_IP3.htm?includeNoSalaryJobs=true&pgc=AB4AAoEAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAd1d%2Bb4AbwECARFcBgSsznIZFPk4fW3sDR3jdfmJewv2%2BLA8TQi8YFhbqVFBx1lHzaVOYjw909IQ%2BIC38g6D%2F3KlCEAfpAkJoqF3AECpEZLOSE%2FDN2rQ33BRLDrpbxe6MwndhK4pkphs5Qq5uzHuklUQKM%2BrUQAA')


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


results = soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class':'hover p-0  job-search-key-kgm6qi exy0tjh1'})


print(results)
```

Comment: You are not getting the desired output because the content in the page are generated dynamically and not requested along with the age request. You ll have to use selenium for this. Let me know if you want to know the selenium solution, I ll code for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to give requests a proper header, and also to revisit Beautiful Soup syntax (afaik you cannot select multiple classes at once, separated by spaces, in selector). The following code works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'}

r = requests.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/united-states-business-intelligence-analyst-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IN1_KO14,43_IP3.htm?includeNoSalaryJobs=true&pgc=AB4AAoEAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAd1d%2Bb4AbwECARFcBgSsznIZFPk4fW3sDR3jdfmJewv2%2BLA8TQi8YFhbqVFBx1lHzaVOYjw909IQ%2BIC38g6D%2F3KlCEAfpAkJoqF3AECpEZLOSE%2FDN2rQ33BRLDrpbxe6MwndhK4pkphs5Qq5uzHuklUQKM%2BrUQAA', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.select('li.eigr9kq0')
for result in results:
    print(result.text)
```